# Anyone know what this it?

Tags: species-identification, marine-biology, invertebrates

[image]

More than 1 washed up on a beach in Ireland..close to some big jellyfish

Comment: Have a look at the tag info for [species-identification](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info)

Comment: Maybe some barnacles?

Answer (score 3):

### Gooseneck barnacles

It appears to be a cluster of [goose barnacles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goose_barnacle) washed up onshore. This is based on the thick, distinct pedicle and the general shape of the asymmetrical valves. Without more information, that’s as accurate as I can probably get you.